# How to output the entries of two lists as equal without evaluation?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

**Question**

So, for example, I have the code here:

```
initialXArr = {Subscript[x, 0][0], Subscript[x, 1][0], 
  Subscript[x, 2][0], Subscript[x, 3][0], Subscript[x, 4][0]}

xarr = {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
```

So I have two arrays now equal to the stuff above. I want code that is able to combine the two lists into one and just output the following list:

```
{Subscript[x, 0][0] == 15, Subscript[x, 1][0]==16, 
 Subscript[x, 2][0] == 17, Subscript[x, 3][0] == 18, 
 Subscript[x, 4][0] == 19}
```

I do not want to evaluate anything, I just need the output to the the above.

**What I've Tried**

Just setting the arrays equal. I just get `False` back.

```
{Subscript[x, 0][0], Subscript[x, 1][0], 
      Subscript[x, 2][0], Subscript[x, 3][0], Subscript[x, 4][0]} == {Subscript[x, 0][0] == 15, Subscript[x, 1][0]==16, 
     Subscript[x, 2][0] == 17, Subscript[x, 3][0] == 18, 
     Subscript[x, 4][0] == 19}
```

This is the only thing I've tried as of now. Honestly, I don't know where to begin trying solutions. This seems like an unusual thing to be trying to get *Mathematica* to do.

**Notes**

- If possible, I would like this code to be extendable to any two lists with matching numbers of entries.

I really appreciate any help I can have on this issue.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @ciao, I just added things I've tried.

Comment: Also, @ciao-- I see plenty of straight up questions get answered here with little to no background. I think the way I've phrased this question is within the bounds of how to ask a question detailed in the [How do I ask a good question?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section...

Comment: "If possible, I would like this code to be extendable to any two lists with matching numbers of entries. " - but your example does not, how should that be interpreted? For equal-length lists, `Thread[initialXArr == xarr]` should do the trick. Word of warning - avoid subscripting for other than display, in general...

Comment: Your arrays are not of equal length.  One is 4 long and the other is 5 long.  Also, what is the logic for skipping `Subscript[x, 1][0]` in the combination.  Or is this a typo.

Comment: The reason you got `False` is probably because the elements of  `inintalXArr` had been assigned values previously, perhaps by inadvertently using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: - These line above are the only two lines in my notebook, and I quit the kernel every time. I don't think that previous assignment is an issue. `Thread[initialXArr == xarr]` also returns False under these conditions. Any other solutions? I fixed the length of the lists, as they should be the same, and that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
MapThread[Equal, {initialXArr, xarr}]

(*  {Subscript[x, 0][0] == 15, Subscript[x, 1][0] == 16, 
 Subscript[x, 2][0] == 17, Subscript[x, 3][0] == 18, 
 Subscript[x, 4][0] == 19}  *)
```

Have fun!